# Socket io cluster on same port

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I need to cluster socket.IO server and want to use same port for all connections
In order to do it I create express server, configure it and then tell socket.IO to listen to this server

```
if(cluster.isMaster){
  var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;
  for (let i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
    cluster.fork();
} else {
  const credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
  const app = express();
  const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
  httpsServer.listen(8003);
  const io = SocketIO.listen(httpsServer);
}
```

But this doesn't work for multiple servers. When I'm trying to connect to socket server I get following message:
`websocket.js?13d9:112 WebSocket connection to 'wss://...' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

But in server side event listener `on("connection", () => {})` works.
I have same code for creating server clusters when I render app and it works just fine.
Socket server works when there's only one socket.IO server listening to this port.

If there's a way to create multiple socket.IO listeners for one port in cluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the answer

> Socket.io is doing multiple requests to perform handshake and establish connection with a client. With a cluster those requests may arrive to different workers, which will break handshake protocol.

So I decided to use [sticky session](https://github.com/indutny/sticky-session) lib for socket.IO and it works exactly as I wanted